# Countdown timer not fully working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer on my website which counts down to Sunday 3pm each week which is when our new sale starts. The timer seems to only decrement the minutes when the seconds reach 30, same with the hours too I think. Here's the code that was supplied for me and the timer can be seen on my webpage here.. http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting-front.aspx

VB...

```
    Dim seconds As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Date.Now, BootSale.nextDOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    Dim days, hours, minutes As Integer
    days = seconds / 86400
    hours = (seconds Mod 86400) / 3600
    minutes = (seconds Mod 3600) / 60
    lblTimer.Text = days & " Day(s) " & hours & " Hour(s) " & minutes & " Minute(s) " ' & seconds Mod 60 & " Seconds"

    If Date.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString = "Sunday" And Date.Now.Hour >= 15 Then
        lblTimer.Text = "NEW SALE JUST GONE LIVE!"
    End If

Protected Sub timer1_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim seconds As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Date.Now, BootSale.nextDOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    Dim days, hours, minutes As Integer
    days = seconds / 86400
    hours = (seconds Mod 86400) / 3600
    minutes = (seconds Mod 3600) / 60
    lblTimer.Text = days & " Day(s) " & hours & " Hour(s) " & minutes & " Minute(s) " & seconds Mod 60 & " Seconds"
End Sub
```

FRONT END...

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>

<asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h2 class="boldStyle">NEW Sale starts in <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></h2></asp:Label></h2>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: It *sounds* like *Rounding* problem (up or down) somewhere... Not sure if my guess is correct thought. Please check this possibility...

Comment: That sounds plausible Ian, thanks for the reply. Still not sure how to fix it though.. I'm just learning programming.. I'll Google how to round up or down unless anyone knows offhand ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inspecting for the cause of the problem in the code that you've provided, I would like to directly suggest another kind of solution.

I suggest you to use my **[TimeMeasurer](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.DateAndTime/Types/TimeMeasurer.vb)** class to represent a countdown or a chronometer, all is guided in a easy way using event handlers to notify about time changes.

[image: https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.DateAndTime/Types/TimeMeasurer.vb]

An example of a countdown using this class:

```
Private WithEvents countdown As New TimeMeasurer()

' Label used to display the remaining time.
Private lblCountdown As Label = Me.Label1

Private Shadows Sub Shown() Handles MyBase.Shown

    ' The time interval for the TimeUpdated event to raise.
    Me.countdown.UpdateInterval = 100 ' ms

    ' Run a countdown of 1 minute.
    Me.countdown.Start(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0R))

End Sub

Private Sub Countdown_TimeUpdated(sender As Object, e As TimeMeasurerUpdatedEventArgs) _
Handles countdown.TimeUpdated

    ' Measure H:M:S:MS
    Me.lblCountdown.Text = 
       String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:000}",
                     e.Remaining.Hours, e.Remaining.Minutes, 
                     e.Remaining.Seconds, e.Remaining.Milliseconds)

    If (e.Elapsed.Subtract(e.Remaining) = e.Goal) Then
        Me.lblCountdown.Text = "Countdown Done!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Another example can be found in the source-code documentation.

Feel free to use it or adapt it as you want. you could inspect the source-code to do it by your own avoiding the issues that you've mentioned.

I hope this can help you!.

Comment: Thank you. As I say, I'm just learning.. Will that code work as it is if I simply add a label in the front end to display it ? Just not totally sure what I'm doing :-)

Comment: @Eggybread Well, I really don't manage ASP.Net, but from that event-handler you can get the **e** event-data with the countdown data to display it as you want, I used a label. The source-code will work as is, the only additional "dependency" or referenced member is this enum: https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.DateAndTime/Enums/TimeMeasurerState.vb and https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.DateAndTime/Types/TimeMeasurerUpdatedEventArgs.vb

Comment: Just notice the important things: Avoid using **DateDiff** (and any member of the **VisualBasic** namespace) and also custom arithmetic calculations, instead of all that you can use a **TimeSpan**, which exposes all the needed values in their properties.